# Telephone number validation in excel

Tags: excel, validation, excel-2010

Can anyone tell me how to create a validation in excel for phone number of format like
1. '+46 12345678
2. '+46 12345678 #123
or so.
Yes it should take ', numbers, space and #.
It should not take any letters.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want this in VBA or pure Excel?

Comment: Pure excel would be helpful. But in case if it cant be achieved with excel then would go for VBA.